# PLSQL check two string if a substring exist in both string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a predefined value from the parameter table varchar column which is below.

'ENGR PACKAGE TYPE,DOCUMENT TYPE,PRODUCT TYPE,MATERIAL TYPE,**PACKAGE CODE**'

So whenever I got a status message like this

'**PACKAGE CODE** "F075" NOT FOUND'

I want to check it with the column in the parameter table,
then I want to have a plsql case when condition that if a string exists in the parameter table,
it will return 'TRUE' else 'FALSE'.

but MY PLSQL query below is not working.

```sql
select CASE WHEN INSTR(upper('PACKAGE CODE "F075" NOT FOUND'), 'ENGR PACKAGE TYPE,DOCUMENT TYPE,PRODUCT TYPE,MATERIAL TYPE,PACKAGE CODE') > 0 THEN
                'TRUE'
            ELSE 'FALSE'
END SAMPLE from dual;
```

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

Your query will return `True` in the following way.

```
select 
    case 
        when instr(upper('PACKAGE CODE "F075" NOT FOUND'), 'PACKAGE CODE') > 0 then
            'TRUE'
        else 
            'FALSE'
    end sample 
from 
    dual;
```

If you wanna check all variants as constant values then use the following query

```
select 
    case 
        when instr(upper('PACKAGE CODE "F075" NOT FOUND'), 'PACKAGE CODE') > 0 then
            'TRUE'
        when instr(upper('PACKAGE CODE "F075" NOT FOUND'), 'ENGR PACKAGE TYPE') > 0 then
            'TRUE'
        when instr(upper('PACKAGE CODE "F075" NOT FOUND'), 'DOCUMENT TYPE') > 0 then
            'TRUE'
        when instr(upper('PACKAGE CODE "F075" NOT FOUND'), 'PRODUCT TYPE') > 0 then
            'TRUE'
        when instr(upper('PACKAGE CODE "F075" NOT FOUND'), 'MATERIAL TYPE') > 0 then
            'TRUE'
        else 
            'FALSE'
    end sample 
from 
    dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
SQL> with
  2  sample (col) as
  3    (select 'PACKAGE CODE "F075" NOT FOUND' from dual),
  4  param (col) as
  5    (select * from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('ENGR PACKAGE TYPE','DOCUMENT TYPE','PRODUCT TYPE','MATERIAL TYPE','PACKAGE CODE')))
  6  select max(case when instr(s.col, p.col) > 0 then 'true'
  7                  else 'false'
  8             end) as result
  9  from sample s cross join param p;

RESUL
-----
true

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

figure this out using regexp like function. feels like a charm.

```
select CASE WHEN regexp_like(upper('Case Outline PACKAGE CODE "948H-01" not found'), 'ENGR PACKAGE TYPE|DOCUMENT TYPE|PRODUCT TYPE|MATERIAL TYPE|PACKAGE CODE')
THEN 'TRUE'
ELSE 'FALSE' END from dual;
```